# Field Integrity exception

Tags: exception

While i am trying to save my work through developer console i am getting the following error. I am unable to solve this problem. But when i did the same thing through Setup->Build->Develop->Apex Classes, i did not get any problem.

Why this is happening if i am using console.

Please provide suitable solutions

[image]

Thanking you in advanced

KS Kumaar

Answer (score 0):

Copy the Deployment ID in your clipboard, and head to:

```
https://[INS].salesforce.com/[PUT-DEPLOYMENT-ID]
```

Click on the `Delete` button to delete the deployment record, and everything should be back to normal.

Comment: Hi Devendra....
i gone through as your instructions, but showing URL No Longer Exists...